# Spring Security configurado em projeto SpringBoot não funciona corretamente em Tomcat externo

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

Meu problema é o seguinte :

Tenho uma aplicação feita com SpringBoot, utilizando o maven, e fazendo uso do Spring Security. Durante todo o processo de desenvolvimento, tudo funciou normalmente, eu utilizei o próprio tomcat do springboot até a finalização da aplicação. Porém ao gerar o WAR da aplicação e fazendo o deploy em um tomcat externo, o spring security não funciona corretamente, ele bloqueia todas as rotas, mesmo que algumas estejam configuradas como rotas permitidas sem autenticação.

Obs: Gerando um fatjar a aplicação também funciona normalmente, já que a aplicação continua fazendo uso do tomcat embarcado. (achei interessante falar)

Segue minhas classes e arquivos :

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Override
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(usuarioService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
        .and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/servico/cadastra").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/autenticacao/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/servico/lista").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/cliente/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/map/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/arquivos/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/sefazapi/noticia/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/sefazapi/autenticacao/logout");

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}


Pom

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Veja se este [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy) te ajuda.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário !

Na verdade não ajuda muito porque eu já segui essa documentação. Eu consigo gerar o WAR normalmente, mas ao fazer o deploy dele em um tomcat (externo) o spring security bloqueia todas as rotas de requisição, até mesmo as que estão liberadas. isso só acontece ao usam o tomcat externo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom descobri o que havia de errado. no tomcat embarcado a aplicação rodava sem um contextPath, então eu mapeava meu controller seguindo o padão.

```
@RestController("meuprojeto/meucontroller")
```

e na requisição eu acessava:

```
http://localhost:8080/meuprojeto/meucontroller/requisicao
```

E funcionava, mas no tomcat externo por default o contextpath é o nome da aplicação, então eu acabava fazendo requisição para a rota errada porque no tomcat externo a rota a cima virava essa:

```
http://localhost:8080/meuprojeto/meuprojeto/meucontroller/requisicao
```

perceba que é meuprojeto consta na url duas vezes.

enfim, resolvi o problema então tirando dos meus controller o "/meuprojeto" e fazendo assim:

```
@RestController("meucontroller")
```

e adicionei nas properties  um contextpath com

```
server.servlet.context-path="/meuprojeto"
```

Dessa forma o tomcat embarcado passou a trabalhar da mesma forma que o tomcat externo, meus mapeamentos ficaram corretos e resolveu esse equívoco